# Translating URL in .htaccess

Tags: url, coldfusion, url-rewriting

Here's what I would like to do
Say I have a domain, www.mydomain.com
I have my coldfusion application in www.mydomain.com/myapp
There is a folder under myapp called x and under x is y
like this
wwwroot - myapp - x - y - index.cfm

So y's URL will be
www.mydomain.com/myapp/x/y

I want the users to type
http://www.mydomain.com/y
Then I want to translate that URL to
http://www.mydomain.com/myapp/?virtualFolder=y

But throughout the session I want the users to only see the original URL

Would you be able to tell me how I could achieve this, may be in .htaccess?
[IIS webserver, Coldfusion 10, shared hosting]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cant use .htaccess in iis its Apache only, iis (depending on the version) has a isapi plugin that can help you there, but if you are on shared hosting you probably wont have access it.  You also wont be able to use the Application.cfc OnMissingTemplate method because generally only direct requests for .cfm[l] or .cfc pages are sent to ColdFusion to be processed.

The only way that I see you being able to accomplish what you want is to use the index.cfm to do your own redirecting.

so instead of

```
http://www.mydomain.com/y
```

you will have to do

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.cfm/y
```

in your index.cfm file you will then parse the url parameter and and using cflocation with status code of 301 to redirect to the actual page.